# how can I install mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have visual studio 2010 and mvc2 installed on my machine. Now I want to install mvc4. How can I do that..

I have tried to install mvc3 and mvc4. But both attempt are failed. Do I need to download and install anything than mvc3.setup and mvc4.setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the standalone installer from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Make sure you have SP1 installed for your Visual Studio 2010 before running the MVC installer.

You don't need to have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed in order to install ASP.NET MVC 4. Also it will work side by side with ASP.NET MVC 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Install ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio first go to this link https://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4?ocid=soc-n-at-loc--TI-TP&WT.mc_id=soc-n-at-loc--TI-TP and install which edition you are using like visual studio 2012 you will get MVC 4 for that edition good lucky

Answer (score 0):

You could use this link http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MVC4VS2010_Loc that you can find in http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 and that will install it using web platform installer (it's easier).